# GLM with Cauchy family

Tags: r, distribution, glm

I would like to train a GLM on R with `family=Cauchy()` but I don't find anything to do it. It looks like it has no sense or maybe Gaussian family does the job. Can someone explain me how to do it or why I can't?

Comment: GLMs only work for conditional distributions in the exponential family, which excludes the Cauchy.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **heavy** package (*Robust Estimation Using Heavy-Tailed Distributions*).

```
library(heavy)
data(ereturns)
fit <- heavyLm(m.marietta ~ CRSP, data = ereturns, family = Cauchy())
summary(fit)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons you can't do this with a GLM (specifically, with `glm()`).

- In the narrow sense, GLMs are only defined for conditional distributions in the *exponential family* (Poisson, binomial, Gaussian, Gamma, and a few others).
- More generally, you can extend GLMs to *quasi-likelihood* models that are based on the mean-variance relationship of a particular distribution. But the Cauchy has undefined/infinite mean and variance, so that won't work.

While @StéphaneLaurent's suggestion to use the `heavy` package is probably best, you can also do this using a general maximum likelihood approach:

```r
library(bbmle)
fit2 <- mle2(m.marietta ~ dcauchy(mu, exp(logsc)), 
             parameters = list(mu~CRSP), 
             start=list(mu=0, logsc=0), 
             data=ereturns)
```

`coef(fit)` and `coef(fit2)` show that the results are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is a Bayesian regression with *t*-distributed errors.

Recall that the Cauchy distribution is equivalent to the *t* distribution with *nu* = 1 degrees of freedom (ref. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Related_distributions)).

So rather than fix the degrees of freedom to be equal to 1, we can estimate them together with the other model parameters.

Here is how to do this with the [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html) package. We'll use the default prior for *nu*, which is Gamma(2, 0.1).

```r
data(ereturns, package = "heavy")

library("brms")

fit.bayes <- brm(
  m.marietta ~ CRSP,
  family = student,
  data = ereturns,
  seed = 1234
)
prior_summary(fit.bayes)
#>                 prior     class coef group resp dpar nlpar lb ub       source
#>                (flat)         b                                       default
#>                (flat)         b CRSP                             (vectorized)
#>  student_t(3, 0, 2.5) Intercept                                       default
#>         gamma(2, 0.1)        nu                             1         default
#>  student_t(3, 0, 2.5)     sigma                             0         default
```

The result of the Bayesian analysis is that, even though the distribution family is heavy tailed, the posterior estimate of the degrees of freedom is between 3 and 4, not 1 (posterior mean = 4.4, posterior mode = 3.3).

```r
summary(fit.bayes)
#>  Family: student 
#>   Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity; nu = identity 
#> Formula: m.marietta ~ CRSP 
#>    Data: ereturns (Number of observations: 60) 
#>   Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
#>          total post-warmup draws = 4000
#> 
#> Population-Level Effects: 
#>           Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> Intercept    -0.01      0.01    -0.02     0.01 1.00     3552     2674
#> CRSP          1.30      0.21     0.90     1.73 1.00     3267     2322
#> 
#> Family Specific Parameters: 
#>       Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
#> sigma     0.06      0.01     0.04     0.08 1.00     2885     3281
#> nu        4.39      2.28     1.96     9.90 1.00     3435     3017
#> 
#> Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
#> and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
#> scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).

mode <- function(x) {
  z <- density(x) 
  z$x[which.max(z$y)] 
}

as_draws_df(fit.bayes) %>%
  summarise(
    across(nu, list(nu_posterior_mean = mean, posterior_mode = mode))
  )
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   nu_mean nu_posterior_mode
#>     <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1    4.39              3.35
```

For comparison, here are the estimates with the [heavy](https://github.com/faosorios/heavy) package as suggested by @StéphaneLaurent.

```r
library("heavy")

fit.heavy <- heavyLm(m.marietta ~ CRSP, data = ereturns, family = Cauchy())
summary(fit.heavy)
#> Linear model under heavy-tailed distributions
#>  Data: ereturns; Family: Cauchy() 
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
#> -0.135080 -0.032849  0.003565  0.044033  0.560639 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std.Error Z value p-value
#> (Intercept) -0.0096   0.0072   -1.3378  0.1810
#> CRSP         1.1638   0.1670    6.9669  0.0000
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 60 total; 58 residual
#> Scale estimate: 0.001479587
#> Log-likelihood: 66.42185 on 3 degrees of freedom
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>